# Apple's iAd doesn't look good on device/simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, iad

This is how my iAd looks on device/simulator. It's happens every time.  Actual size of banner is right, but content size is wrong (you can see it on my picture). **Maybe, when app goes live this problem will be fixed?** Any help, thanks.

My app using cocos2d v2.1, landscape only.

This is my createBanner code:

```
 _adBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
_adBannerView.delegate = self;

    CGSize sizeToFit = [_adBannerView sizeThatFits:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view].frame.size];
[_adBannerView setFrame:CGRectMake(([[CCDirector sharedDirector] view].frame.size.width - sizeToFit.width)/2.0f, 0, sizeToFit.width, sizeToFit.height)];

[_adBannerView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

CGRect frame = _adBannerView.frame;
frame.origin.y = -frame.size.height;
frame.origin.x = 0.0f;

_adBannerView.frame = frame;

AppController * myDelegate = (((AppController*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate));
[myDelegate.navController.view addSubview:self.adBannerView];
```

[image: This]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it. 
Problem was with new iOS 8 Feature when you can use **LaunchImage.xib** instead of Assets catalog. When you use resizable **.xib** file it works perfect, but iAd don't response that you are in Landscape mode.